# TensorFlow: How to create custom "wine_quality" dataset from "csv"?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I found it extremely difficult to create a custom dataset that can be used to replace the `wine_quality` dataset from `tensorflow_datasets` so that I can reuse other code with my own data:

> import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

> dataset = tfds.load(name="wine_quality", as_supervised=True,
> split="train")

After loading, the wine_quality dataset:

> Type:           PrefetchDataset
>
> String form:    <PrefetchDataset shapes: ({alcohol: (), chlorides: (),
> citric acid: (), density: (), fixed acidit <...> ulphates: tf.float64,
> total sulfur dioxide: tf.float32, volatile acidity: tf.float32},
> tf.int32)> Length:         4898 File:
> c:\users\haozhen\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py
>
> Docstring:      A `Dataset` that asynchronously prefetches its input.
> Init docstring: See `Dataset.prefetch()` for details.
>
> Args:   input_dataset: The input dataset.   buffer_size: See
> `Dataset.prefetch()` for details.   slack_period: (Optional.) An
> integer. If non-zero, determines the number
> of GetNext calls before injecting slack into the execution. This may
> reduce CPU contention at the start of a step. Note that a tensorflow
> user should not have to set this manually; enable this behavior
> automatically via `tf.data.Options.experimental_slack` instead. Defaults
> to None.

How can I create my own wine_quality dataset from csv?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link to get details on creating custom Dataset through TFDS CLI.
https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset